# Prove or disprove: If $z_n \neq 0$ and $z_n \rightarrow l\neq 0$, then $\text{Arg}\ z_n \rightarrow \text{Arg}\ l$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-numbers

Prove or disprove: If $z_n \neq 0$ and $z_n \rightarrow l\neq 0$, then $\text{Arg}\ z_n \rightarrow \text{Arg}\ l$.

By $\text{Arg}\ z$ we mean principal value of $\text{arg}\ z$, i.e., the $\theta$ lies in $(-\pi, \pi]$ for which $z=re^{i\theta}$ holds.

My attempt: If $z_n = -1 +i\frac{1}{n}$ then $l= -1$.  So, $\text{Arg}\ z_n = 0$, but $\text{Arg}\ l = \pi$.

Is it correct?

Comment: In your attempt, $\operatorname{Arg} z_n$ should be somewhere just below $\pi$ too, not $0$.

Comment: Please edit to include precisely what *principal value of arg* means.

Comment: OK, now that you've included the definition ... Revisit your values of $\text{Arg}\,z_n$ and $\text{Arg}\,l$.

Comment: I see that you changed the definition. Nice work! :P Have you thought any more about your example?

Comment: @TedShifrin Sir, I think I have done  a wrong calculation of $\text{Arg}\ z_n$.

Comment: You seem to be saying that $\arg\left(-1+\frac in\right)=0$.  That is not right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider any sequence $ z_n = x + y i $ with $ y < 0 $ such that $ z_n \rightarrow -1 $ and try to show that Arg $  z_n \rightarrow -\pi $. A small variation of the sequence you suggest will work.

Comment: Do the sequence $z_n = -1 -i\frac{1}{n}$ will work? I found that $\text{Arg}\ z_n \rightarrow -\pi$, but $\text{Arg}\ l= \pi$.

Comment: Yes, @userspr22, this is finally correct.